# C# DateTime.AddMonth with day non-existent in next month

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

If I have `DateTime date = new DateTime("1/31/2010");` and I call `date.AddMonth(1)`. Will I get "2/28/2010" or will it freak out because "2/31/2010" doesn't exist? Or will I get "3/3/2010"?

(Also I'm not near a computer with Visual Studio)

Comment: I down voted this question because this could have easily been tested. I realize the user said they were not near a computer but they could have checked when they were back at one.

Comment: I upvoted because AddMonth is a nonsense : a month lasting 28, 29, 30 or 31 days? It's a per framework arbitrary decision : use AddDays() instead.

Comment: I absolutely agree. This method calculates some date, maybe even along the "common sense" of majority, but in no way it is an "add" operation. D+1month+1month is not necesarily D+2months, i.e. 31Jan+1m+1m=28Mar while 31Jan+2M=31Mar. Happy debugging from ill-structured historical time measurement.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

- [DateTime.AddMonths Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)

> If the resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the last valid day of the resulting month is used. For example, March 31st + 1 month = April 30th.

Answer (score 7):

You'll get the end day of the next month, so 2/28.

Answer (score 4):

It will do a proper DateTime month addition and return 2/28/2010

Answer (score 4):

It will not break, it will give you 2/28/2010